# Public rest parameters in constructor

Tags: typescript, typescript1.4

i watched a tutorial of typescript, that uses Version 1.0.0.
There was a sample of a class, using a public rest parameter in the constructor:

```
class XYZ {
   constructor(public firstname: string, public lastname: string, ...public emails: Array<string>) {
    }
}
```

How to do this in Version 1.5.0?
If i define the class like this, i got several errors:

```
type.ts(14,75): error TS1005: '=' expected.
type.ts(14,81): error TS1005: ',' expected.
type.ts(14,88): error TS1005: '=' expected.
type.ts(14,96): error TS1109: Expression expected.
```

Thanks
Mario

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[There is an oversight in the spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2733), but the rest parameter can't be public or private. Here is how to fix the code:

```
class XYZ {
    public emails: string[];
    constructor(public firstName: string, public lastName: string, ...emails: string[]) {
        this.emails = emails;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `public emails: string[]` to avoid the member getting the `any` type.